# Use RDOJunkEmailOptions to remove blocked senders?

Tags: outlook-redemption

I want to use the RDOJunkEmailOptions object to extract the list of blocked senders for each account, process it externally, and rebuild the list in Outlook. My extraction and external processing are working fine, but when ready to reimport the lists I can't find a way to remove the existing lists.  Is there a method available to delete blocked senders either en masse or one-by-one?

I have tried

```
oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Clear

For lCtr = oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Count To 1 Step -1
    oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Remove (lCtr)
Next lCtr

For lCtr = oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Count To 1 Step -1
    oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Delete (lCtr)
Next lCtr
```

and a couple of other usual method names.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to call Save:

```
oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Clear
oJunkOpt.Save
```

Comment: I actually had the save call in the code, just didn't list it here. The code using Clear runs without error, but does not actually clear the list.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. hat is the value of `oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Count` after you call `oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Clear`?

Comment: Hmm, this has gotten stranger. I'm seeing .Count as 0 BEFORE the Clear, yet in the Outlook UI I see hundreds of addresses in the list. Here's a more complete view of the code:

Comment: Set mrSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
mrSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
Err.Clear
    
oAcct = mrSession.Accounts.Item("<acct name>")
Set oJunkOpt = oAcct.JunkEmailOptions

Debug.Print oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Count
oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Clear
oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Save
Debug.Print oJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Count

Immediate window output:
 0 
 0 

Screenshot of the list before and after (identical) will follow.

Comment: Apparently I can't add a screenshot here. Trust me, there are a lot of addresses in the list.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right account? Can you try to use `RDOSession.JunkEmailOptions`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I have the right account - I checked it by looking at the value of the account name after each step. To make sure, I ran the entire script (add statements commented out), which should have cleared the blocked and trusted senders lists for each of the 14 accounts. Interesting result: None of the blocked senders lists were cleared, but all of the trusted senders lists were. (So, again, no question that the accounts were correct.) Per your suggestion, I reload the trusted senders lists and ran the following:

Comment: Set lroJunkOpt = mrSession.JunkEmailOptions
    lroJunkOpt.BlockedSenders.Clear
    lroJunkOpt.TrustedSenders.Clear
    lroJunkOpt.Save

Comment: Same result: The trusted senders lists were all cleared, the blocked senders lists were not.

Comment: Can you run the following script? I ran it from OUtlookSpy (click Script, paste the script, click Run): `set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set JunkOptions = Session.JunkEmailOptions
for each addr in JunkOptions.BlockedSenders
  Debug.Print addr
next`

Comment: I ran your script using OutlookSpy. It ran successfully but printed no addresses. When I added Debug.Print JunkOptions.BlockedSenders.Count before the For Each, it printed 0. But in the Outlook UI, many addresses are shown.

Comment: What are the messages stores (Exchange, PST, etc.) are in the profile?

Comment: The default account is Exchange, the other 13 are all IMAP (OST). There are also several PST stores that are not tied to mail accounts, and therefore don't have junk senders lists.

Comment: Do you see the expected list when you right click on an email in the default store, select Junk | Junk E-mail Options | Blocked Senders?

Comment: Yes, as I said, the Outlook UI (meaning the blocked senders list) shows all of the addresses, amounting to several hundred, even after I run the VBA code and/or the OutlookSpy script.

Comment: I have found more evidence of a disconnect between the Redemption JunkEmailOptions list and the Outlook UI blocked senders list. After running my code to clear the blocked senders lists last week, I have spent the week adding a few more blocked senders to the list using the Block Sender option in Outlook. Today I ran my extraction again (which uses the Redemption object), and only the new entries were exported. All of the old and new entries are still showing in the Outlook UI list. Interestingly, Outlook is still blocking messages from the old list as well as the new entries

Comment: That actually makes sense - Redemption loads both registry based and mailbox based lists, but uses the most recent. In your case Outlook probably merges the two. Send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com, and I can get you a version that merges the two lists.

Comment: Great! I will do so. Thanks!